# Finding matches in two lists

Tags: python

I'am creating my first python project called hangman. And i'am stuck in place, where i need to compare letters from given word and if all letters is correct (not depending from order), program shows, that i won.

```
import random

class HangMan():

    def __init__(self):
        self.words_list = 'sunny', 'number', 'darius', 'calendar', 'table'
        self.words_randomizer = random.choice(self.words_list)




    def guess_letter(self):
        word_splitter = list(self.words_randomizer)
        empty_list = []
        while True:
            guess_letter = str(input('Please enter letter'))
            empty_list.append(guess_letter)
            if guess_letter in word_splitter:
                print(f'You are correct, there is letter - {guess_letter}, please guess another !')
                continue
            elif sorted(empty_list) == sorted(word_splitter):
                print('Congrats ! You won')
                break



8hm = HangMan()
print(hm.words_randomizer)
hm.guess_letter()
```

I thought, if i'll create empty list and append guessing letters it will work. But it dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only add the letter to the list when it's correct, also don't use an `elif`, finding a letter isn't an excluding condition for solving the exercice, that's the opposite, you need to find letter to solve it so put the winning condition into the valid-guessing block

```
def guess_letter(self):
    word_splitter = sorted(self.words_randomizer)
    guesses = []
    while True:
        guess_letter = input('Please enter letter: ')

        if guess_letter in guesses:
            print("You already test that")
            
        elif guess_letter in word_splitter:
            print(f'You are correct, there is letter - {guess_letter}, please guess another !')
            guesses.append(guess_letter)
            if sorted(guesses) == word_splitter:
                print('Congrats ! You won')
                break
```

Also

- check for already tested letter
- `input` already returns a string

Answer (score 2):

You should only append to the empty list if the word is correct, like this:

```
import random

class HangMan():

    def __init__(self):
        self.words_list = 'sunny', 'number', 'darius', 'calendar', 'table'
        self.words_randomizer = random.choice(self.words_list)




    def guess_letter(self):
        word_splitter = list(self.words_randomizer)
        empty_list = []
        while True:
            guess_letter = str(input('Please enter letter'))
            if guess_letter in word_splitter:
                print(f'You are correct, there is letter - {guess_letter}, please guess another !')
                empty_list.append(guess_letter)
            if sorted(empty_list) == sorted(word_splitter):
                print('Congrats ! You won')
                break



hm = HangMan()
print(hm.words_randomizer)
hm.guess_letter()
```

Although, this algorithm has a flaw, that suppose the word is sunny, and I input "s" twice, it will add it twice to the empty_list, which will then give a logical error in the game.

So, you can try popping element from the list instead:

```
    def guess_letter(self):
        word_splitter = list(self.words_randomizer)
        while True:
            guess_letter = str(input('Please enter letter'))
            if guess_letter in word_splitter:
                print(
                    f'You are correct, there is letter - {guess_letter}, please guess another !')
                word_splitter.remove(guess_letter)
            if len(word_splitter) == 0:
                print('Congrats ! You won')
                break
```

Comment: @user17301834 I don't think that is how the list function should work. You can actually try running the code and adding print statements to see the logs as it is working well right now.

Comment: Otherwise, please do let me know

Comment: @Divayessh, no sorry, you were completely right. I'll delete my comment, but yes, I thought `.split('')` was needed to create a list of all characters in a string, turns out I was a bit of an idiot.

Comment: @user17301834 No problem at all :)

Comment: Nice talking to you :)